# PHP MsSQL WAMP - Couldn't connect to MSSQL

Tags: php, sql-server

I've downloaded SQLSRV32.EXE from [the official MSSQL Driver for PHP](https://www.microsoft.com/en-us/download/details.aspx?id=20098) and extracted php_sqlsrv_56_ts.dll & php_pdo_sqlsrv_56_ts.dll into `C:\wamp\bin\php\php5.6.19\ext`

Added the following declaration in the php.ini from the WAMP menu.

```
extension=php_pdo_sqlsrv_56_ts.dll
extension=php_sqlsrv_56_ts.dll
```

I then run the sample code from the [reference page](http://zurb.com/forrst/posts/Install_Microsoft_SQL_Server_Driver_with_WAMP-GAi).

I couldn't connect to the MS SQL Server due to the following error

```
Connection could not be establish
Array ( [0] => Array ( [0] => IMSSP [SQLSTATE] => IMSSP [1] => -49 [code] => -49 [2] => This extension requires the Microsoft ODBC Driver 11 for SQL Server. Access the following URL to download the ODBC Driver 11 for SQL Server for x86: http://go.microsoft.com/fwlink/?LinkId=163712 [message] => This extension requires the Microsoft ODBC Driver 11 for SQL Server. Access the following URL to download the ODBC Driver 11 for SQL Server for x86: http://go.microsoft.com/fwlink/?LinkId=163712 ) [1] => Array ( [0] => IM002 [SQLSTATE] => IM002 [1] => 0 [code] => 0 [2] => [Microsoft][ODBC Driver Manager] Data source name not found and no default driver specified [message] => [Microsoft][ODBC Driver Manager] Data source name not found and no default driver specified ) )
```

I've tried to download the ODBC Driver 13 (for Windows 10) but it is not working. Can someone tell me what I'm doing wrong?

[image: Version incompatible]

Comment: Have you downloaded the correct file for your specific operating system?

Answer (score 0):

As I can see - ODBC Driver 13 is not supported on your system and the required one is ODBC Driver 11.

https://www.microsoft.com/en-us/download/details.aspx?id=36434